# Change default launcher programmattically in Mi TV

Tags: android, android-launcher, television, mi

I am developing android application for Mi TV which should be set as launcher. How to achieve this? redirect me if already answer. Home launcher for other Tv can be changed. Can I do the same in Mi TVs.